# Is it possible to make raid 0 from 2 ssd drives?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, raid, raid-0

Like in the title, is it possible. I was thinking about that last year but everybody told me that it's not possible due to controller issues. Today I revisited that idea after seeing awesome vids on youtube running two ssd in raid 0. I'm running 2xhdd in raid 0 and I'm wondering wether to change 2x64gb sdd raid 0 for system and 2xhdd for files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have always configured two SSD drives in a RAID 0 format. However, the issue is that the controller/software could not implement the TRIM feature on the newer (now more standard) drives. TRIM was where the data deleted from the SSD would be wiped as it was deleted. This would cause drives that were getting close to being full to slow down. Now-a-days, you can configure them in a RAID if the RAID Controller supports TRIM of the SSD in the RAID setup.

Here is an article of Intel incorporating TRIM in the their RST Software.

http://www.tomshardware.com/news/Intel-RST-SSD-TRIM-RAID,14048.html

Here's more of an updated article. It looks like the Intel RST Software required for TRIM support on RAID configurations are available, but will not be officially released until later this year.

http://news.softpedia.com/news/Intel-Plans-to-Bring-TRIM-Support-to-SSDs-with-RST-11-5-11-6-Driver-249504.shtml

However, since TRIM is an OS Supported/Driver Driven technology, you may be able to find a third party SATA RAID Controller that has TRIM Support built in.

Comment: so basically now, it's a question wether my motherboard support it?

Comment: Yea, it will most likely come down to the chipset.

Comment: It looks like their new software to be released this year will date back to ICH9R which is great for older hardware. Another thing to consider is that there are several programs out there that will do a manual TRIM for you instead of having it done automatically via the controller software.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible.

**Pros**:
Larger Single Virtual Disk and cheaper than buying a large SSD to accommodate the same amount of space if you already have an SSD.

**Cons**:
No TRIM Support (on older models),less reliable than single drive, and less performance than a single drive in random transfers.

Comment: -1 While it probably is cheaper to buy 2x 128GB drives instead of a 256GB drive, it usually is cheaper to buy one 128GB drive than 2x 64BG drives. No TRIM support is an universal issues, not limited to older models. There shouldn't be any drop in random transfers, rather an improvement in some cases.

Comment: I should have specified by saying if you already have one SSD it's (usually) cheaper to buy a second of that size than to buy one of 2x the size.